# In Swift, what's the difference between calling UINavigationController() vs UINavigationController.init()?

Tags: swift, swift3, ios10, xcode8

In Swift, what's the difference between calling `UINavigation()` vs `UINavigation.init()`? They both seem to return valid instance of `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 5):

`UINavigationController()` and `UINavigationController.init()` are the exact same thing.  You can verify this by typing both into a Playground and then <kbd>option</kbd>-clicking on them.  Both bring up the documentation for the same initializer.

The Swift convention is to use just the type name (without `.init`).

Comment: The only place where you seem to need to call `init()` explicitly (as far as I can tell) is `super.init()` when overriding an initializer...

Comment: @NicolasMiari a good point, but as an addendum it might be worth noting, however, that `super` is not a type but a special Swift prefix used to access superclass methods and properties (not just `init(...)`). Its use cases and access is more similar to an instance of a type rather than a type itself (except for, particularly, initializers of the superclass).

Comment: Indeed, it's not the same as `Classname.init()`

Comment: To clarify – the *only* place where you can omit `.init` in order to call an initialiser is when you specify the type by name (although this is the majority of cases). All other cases will require the use of `.init` in order to access the initialiser (for example, `type(of: someValue).init()`). The relevant part of the language guide [is here btw (under "Initializer Expression")](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/function-call-expression).

Answer (score 4):

For some given type (e.g. `UINavigationController`), there is no difference between *a call* to `UINavigationController()` or `UINavigationController.init()`, but the latter syntax can (without the `()` call) be useful when referencing an initializer of some given type, say `Foo`, in contexts where we want to make use of a closure (or reference to a closure) which is to have

- zero or more arguments, and
- return type `Foo`,

e.g., `(Int, Double) -> Foo`. In these contexts, using the syntax `Foo.init` may prove useful: rather than explicitly letting a closure repeatedly *call* a known initializer (piping the closure's arguments to the initializer), we may use (a reference to) the initializer direcly as the closure instead. If there's no ambiguity in the argument of the initializers of `Foo`, a reference to `Foo.init` in some given closure type context will resolve, using type inference, to the correct initializer.

E.g., consider the following example

```
struct Foo {
    let foo: Int

    // (Int) -> Foo
    init(foo: Int) {
        self.foo = 2*foo
    }

    // (Int, Int) -> Foo
    init(foo: Int, bar: Int) {
        self.foo = foo + bar
    }

    // () -> Foo
    init() {
        self.foo = 42
    }
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3]
let fooArr1 = arr.map { Foo(foo: $0) }
let fooArr2 = arr.map(Foo.init)
                 /* map operation expects a single argument of type (Int) -> Foo, 
                    which we generally supply as a trailing closure. In this context,
                    Swift can, without ambiguity (since we have none, is this example), 
                    find the correct overload among the initializers of Foo */
print(fooArr1.map { $0.foo }, fooArr2.map { $0.foo }) // [2, 4, 6] [2, 4, 6]

let emptyTupArr = [(), (), ()]
let fooArr3 = emptyTupArr.map(Foo.init) // inferred to be the '() -> Foo' initializer
print(fooArr3.map { $0.foo }) // [42, 42, 42]
```

Answer (score 0):

From Apple docs, you use `init` when you are subclassing the controller.  It looks like without passing a value to the unit function, it just returns a standard UINavigationController

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller